# Python - Series Objects are Mutable - Address Parsing

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to create a new column in a data frame that will parse out an address from a string. When attempting to do this, I receive the following error:

```
("'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed", u'occurred at index pk')
```

I have seen other questions similar to this on this site but don't quite understand how it applies to my code:

```
import usaddress, re, pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=TEST;UID=test;PWD=test")

sql = "select top 10 pk, address from test..test"
df = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)

pattern = re.compile(".+\\b[0-9]{5}\\b")

def extract(pat):
    print pat
    test = pattern.findall(pat)
    return str(test[0])

i = 0

for i in df.iterrows():
    df[i]['cleansed_address'] = df.apply(lambda x: extract(df[i]['descrsched']))
    i+=1
```

Comment: `df['descrsched'].apply(extract)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### MCVE

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2,], [3, 4]])
df

# This is a tuple (index value, Series object that represents row)
#   |
#   v    
for i in df.iterrows():
    print(df[i])
#            ^
#            |
# This is you trying to tell Pandas to use a tuple
# in which the second element is a Series as a reference for a column name
```

#### Resolve X/Y problem

```
df['cleansed_address'] = df['descrsched'].str.findall(pat).str[0]
```

Comment: Thank you! So much simpler than it seemed.